# YouTube API Delete video with client login

Tags: curl, google-api, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API with ClientLogin in PHP and cURL.

I sent the request like this:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

I got all information of that video in atom+xml format as the response.

Is this the correct response ?

After 1.5 Hours, I cannot see this video deleted.

Didn't find specific example for Video Deletion with ClientLogin API.

The system was implemeted with ClientLogin before November, 2010.

Now, I see on YouTube API help that, they don't recommend this method.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin.html

Can anybody help to solve this with ClientLogin method ?

Zend library with ClientLogin is working fine.

I digged in Zend library for YouTube API ClientLogin and found that it uses stream_socket_client for API request.

I've extracted the core code here:

```
$context = stream_context_create();

$socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://gdata.youtube.com:80', $errno, $errstr, 10, 4, $context);

stream_set_timeout($socket, 10); // To set a timeout for reading/writing data over the socket

$request =  "DELETE /feeds/users/".$_SESSION["youTubeUser"]."/uploads/".$videoId." HTTP/1.1".PHP_EOL."
             Host: gdata.youtube.com".PHP_EOL."
             Connection: close".PHP_EOL."
             X-GData-Key: key=".DEVELOPER_KEY.PHP_EOL."
             Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authKey.PHP_EOL."
             Accept-encoding: identity".PHP_EOL."
             Content-Type: application/atom+xml".PHP_EOL."
             Content-Length: 0".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

fwrite($socket, $request);

while (($line = fgets($socket)) !== false) {
    $gotStatus = $gotStatus || (strpos($line, 'HTTP') !== false);
    if ($gotStatus) {
        $rspns .= $line;
        if (rtrim($line) === '') break;
    }
}

echo $errno." => ".$errstr."<br />Response: ";var_dump($rspns); exit;
```

as a response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 11858 Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 10:59:05 GMT Server: GFE/2.0
```

Now, can anybody catch anything.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried deleting a YouTube video by sending a DELETE request authenticated with ClientLogin and it worked correctly.

Are you sending any content in the body of your request? DELETE calls take no payload.
For your reference, here are my request and the response:

```
DELETE https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER-KEY
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=DQAA...
GData-Version: 2.0
Host: gdata.youtube.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
GData-Version: 2.0
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 18:23:52 GMT
Expires: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 18:23:52 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Server: GSE
Content-Type: text/html
```